# yUML images in Markdown content of questions or answers

Tags: support, images

### Solution

**It turns out using Chrome makes the issue go away. All is fine. I was using [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29).**

btw: Opera Touch, on mobile devices also works ok.

**Thus the original question is now just a multi layered confusion.**

### Original Question

Is there a way to add yUML images to questions/answers in Markdown?

Here is an example:

```
<img src="http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/[Customer]->[Billing Address]" >
```

For some reason this does not work...

### Edit

It seemed one must encode that link. But ...

```
https://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/%5ByUML%5D-%3E%5BCHROME%20Address%5D
```

---

[image]

---

Above we should see the simple diagram. I have seen it, but not any more?

If one draws yUML diagram using their [page for that](https://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/draw), one can take the generated image address. For example,

```
     <img src="https://yuml.me/ee4eb8ed.png" />
```

That looks like a valid and simple URL. But for some reason it does not show an image. It was supposed to show up bellow here:

---

[image]

---

No image above. Perhaps yUML is not "keeping" it? In any case, this should be much simpler and smoother and transparent process. But currently it is not.

This depends on the yuml.me server side, which might not work "sometimes" it seems.

---

Here is the diagram image from Imgur:

[image]

Comment: Replace `>` in the URL by `&gt;`. This isn’t valid HTML. Also, use `https`. Alternatively, encode the URL as `https://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/%5BCustomer%5D-%3E%5BBilling%20Address%5D`.

Comment: Ah of course, elementary ... if was to obvious to figure it out .. Thanks

Comment: The shortened urls form [yuml drawing page](https://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/draw) do not work. For example `<img src="https://yuml.me/3620467f.svg" />` ... This all seems very delicate, when using on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the proper HTML encoding for the image link (thanks Sebastian Simon for correcting me on why this works):

```
https://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/[Customer]-%3E[Billing%20Address]
```

[image: The image the user couldn't post]

This was obtained by selecting "Copy image address" on the image itself, then the image loader from the answer toolbar accepted the image's link.

Comment: your diagram has a "staying power"  if it is not just an image ? In the markup of my question there are no more diagram images shown ...

Comment: This is image from imgur not an yuml generated diagram image ...  and that it seems does not work. Somehow it was working but not any more> Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Chef Sorry, but I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking in your first comment. As for imgur: Whenever you use an image on Stack Overflow, unless it's a question about the actual syntax for generating an off-site resource, you should always import the image to Stack Overflow using the image button in the question/answer toolbar. That will save the image on Stack's Imgur account so that if the link breaks in the future, the images on Stack Overflow keep working. So I pasted the link into the Image by Url option, and Stack was able to load it to Imgur for use.

Comment: Ok I think it is simple: imgur hosted images (naturally) show ok, but yuml.me delivered images are not showing up ...your answer shows the imgur hosted image, not what is yuml.me supposed to deliver

Comment: Forget it all. Opera desktop browser is not showing them yUML diagrams. Chrome does. Most peculiarly Opera Touch on mobile devices, also works ok.